# code review: Python list concatenation elements to string

Tags: python, list

hey i have a Problem solving a Problem
that Looks like this:

the Output is exactly what i need but i wonder is there isnt a more elegant
way to do that?

```
list = [["key189","0","apples"],
        ["key622","1","bananas"],
        ["key233","2","bacon"],
        ["key454","3","bread"],
        ["key35","4","jam"],
        ["key6","5","coffee"]]

for e in list:
    if e[0] == "key622":
        key622 = e[2]
    if e[0] == "key189":
        key189 = e[2]
    if e[0] == "key35":
        key35 = e[2]
    if e[0] == "key454":
        key454 = e[2]
    if e[0] == "key233":
        key233 = e[2]
    if e[0] == "key6":
            key6 = e[2]

string_form = "|".join([key6, key35, key233, key189, key622, key454])


print(string_form)
# prints coffee|jam|bacon|apples|bananas|bread
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on the sister site [`CodeReview`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The order of your joining is rather random.

Comment: It's a very bad data structure you are using , I think your _key_ variables are unique , so I suggest you use a `Dictionary`

Comment: A dictionary would be a great solution but i dont know how to Combine the keys and the values so i come out in the correct order of those keys (key6, key35, key233, key189, key622, key454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a using a dictionary will make your life easier.

```
dt = {itm[0]:itm[2] for itm in list}
```

`dt` will be:

```
{'key189': 'apples',
 'key233': 'bacon',
 'key35': 'jam',
 'key454': 'bread',
 'key6': 'coffee',
 'key622': 'bananas'}

string_form = "|".join(dt.values())
```

`string_form` will be:

```
'coffee|apples|bacon|jam|bananas|bread'
```

you can get any key's value: like this:

```
dt.get('key35')
```

For the specific string use this:

```
"|".join([dt.get('key6'), dt.get('key35'), dt.get('key233'), dt.get('key189'), dt.get('key622'), dt.get('key454')])
```

Try not to use variable names like `list`, `dict` etc.

Comment: thats great! but i Need that specific order of key6, key35, key233, key189, key622, key454

Comment: got it! i think that i exactly what i had in mind. great idea thanks a lot!!

Comment: Just use dt.get(key) syntax. I shall edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify anything about order, this should do:

```
data = [["key189","0","apples"],
        ["key622","1","bananas"],
        ["key233","2","bacon"],
        ["key454","3","bread"],
        ["key35","4","jam"],
        ["key6","5","coffee"]]
print("|".join([pair[2] for pair in data]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"|".join(fruit for _, _, fruit in list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcording the order in an if-else construct, you could just define it in a list, and then sort according to the index the item has in that list:

```
order = ['key6', 'key35', 'key238', 'key189', 'key622', 'key454']
print("|".join(y[2] for y in sorted([x for x in lst if x[0] in order], key = lambda i: order.index(i[0]))))
```